# Passing a function into an EJS template for use in an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, templates, ejs

I'm trying to pass a function into an EJS template and have it be set to an onclick event in the template.  Is this possible?

In other words, something like this

```
var clickHandler = function() { console.log("I am in the click handler!"); }
var template = new EJS({ url: "/template.ejs"  });
var html = template.render({ clickHandler: clickHandler })
$("#target").html(html);
```

Where the template looks something like

```
<p onclick='clickHandler'>Click Me</p>
```

Comment: Looks like you can accomplish something like that. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30539675/4875631) solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The problem is more in getting the syntax right for the onclick="funcName";  I can do onclick="<% clickHandler %>, but that doesn't do anything on click.  I can also do onclick="<% clickHandler() %> but that executes the function as soon as it's parsed

Comment: @user3412416 did you found any solution for this :- " I can also do onclick="<% clickHandler() %> but that executes the function as soon as it's parsed "

Answer (score 4):

- You should put your `js` function in the `.ejs` file instead of the server file.
- You should pass the function name instead of the entire function code.

**app.js**

```
var html = template.render({ clickHandler:"func1();" })
```

**EJS**

```
<p onclick='<%= clickHandler %>'>Click Me</p>

<script>
  function func1(){
    console.log("I am in the click handler 1!"); 
  }
  function func2(){
    console.log("I am in the click handler 2!"); 
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Now, how can I pass parameter by doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass arguments like below

< p onclick="clickHandler('<%= obj.key %>')">Click Me< /p>