# Is it possible to make an SPA with only expressJS?

Tags: express

I am new to expressJS, as I know ExpressJS generates clearly an MVC architecture, so I would like to serve **my index.jade** with different requests coming from **index.js**, I mean like this :

**The first request gets all the user's IDs**

**The second request counts all the users**

All requests in one file:

**index.js**

```
...
var getAllusersID = 'SELECT * FROM keyspace_name.users'; // Request 1
var CountAllusers = 'SELECT COUNT(users) AS Allusers FROM keyspace_name.users'; // Request 2
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  client.execute(getAllusersID,[], function(err, result){
    if(err){
      res.status(404).send({msg:err});
    } else{
      res.render('index', {
        usersID: result.rows
      });
    }
  });

})

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  client.execute(CountAllusers,[], function(err, result){
    if(err){
      res.status(404).send({msg:err});
    } else{
      res.render('index', {
        AllusersNum: result.rows[0].Allusers
      });
    }
  });

})
module.exports = router;
```

**index.jade**

```
h1 first request
ul
  each Ust in i usersID
    li #{Ust.userid} // fist request shows here

h1 second request
ul
  li #{AllusersNum} // second request shows here
```

**I only get the result for the first request in the browser, why not the second one?**

When I remove the first request in index.js, the second request shows up in the browser, why not both simultaneously?

Comment: There are two issues. Once you call `res.render` the middleware chain ends. No middleware after that will be executed. Secondly, if you want to use one middleware after another, they must be in that order and you need to invoke `next` for the next middleware to be processed. If you want to combine templates, then look into template partials.

Comment: You mean the next() method before the second request ? I tried that one but didn’t work,  Can you please  share a reference or explain how to do it by an example ?

Comment: I tried the template partials in the `index.ejs`, it renders only the static `.ejs` pages for example I can include in `index.ejs` this `<% include partials/header.ejs %>` , note that the `header.ejs` file contains only html codes, if I try to call variable from middleware in `header.ejs` to display data from my DB, the `index.ejs` cannot recognize that variable

Comment: Try using `<%- include('partials/header', { variables: variablesObject }); %>`. If you want to pass variables that are present in `index.ejs` then you need to pass them as argument to the include function. Also notice the script-let tag used to avoid double escaping HTML.

Comment: `ReferenceError: /home/testbed/Desktop/app/views/index.ejs:14

    12|     <div class="container">

    13|      <% include partials/header.ejs %>

 >> 14|      <%- include('partials/commit', { variables: variablesObject }) %>

    15|      <% include partials/footer.ejs %>

    16|     </div>

    17|     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

variablesObject is not defined`

Comment: there is the same error when I add what you suggested

Comment: The last approach I can suggest can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44141872/ejs-include-functions-defined-in-a-separate-ejs-file/44143908#44143908

Comment: I will try this one, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have recreated a small portion of your code. I used some object in the template that I passed to the render method and used the value from specific object properties in my partials. Please check this out.

index.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const variables = {
    partial1Text: 'This is for partial 1',
    partial2Text: 'This is for partial 2'
};

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname);

app.get('/', (req, res, nxt) => {
    res.render('index', { variables: variables });
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log('EJS Test server started'));
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>EJS Partials in Action</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%- include('partial1', { text: variables.partial1Text }) %>
        <%- include('partial2', { text: variables.partial2Text }) %>
    </body>
</html>
```

partial1.ejs

```
<h2><%= text %></h2>
```

partial2.ejs

```
<h3><%= text %></h3>
```

In my case, both the values were output as expected, one after the other as specified by the order of the `include`. Also see that I have first passed the variables to the index.ejs which then passed the relevant components to the partials. Finally, note the `<%= %>` tag use. It was used to print the value of the `text` property as a string. Hope this helps.

Comment: If this solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. You're welcome.

Comment: Just FYI: your question is unclear. SPA is a single page. Like many SPA in Angular, Vue, you need to consider Client Side Rendering for components. The back end can be really any suitable REST API. In your case, maybe you have your template rendered before server start. You can send this template as response to initial request. From then on, just deal with JSON data request and response. If you need to pass extra template, consider passing string to the client app and have it rendered on client side using EJS. Hope this helps.

Comment: You’re right, I think the best way is to use express only for restfull API and angular vuejs and react for the frontend

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? If so consider accepting it by clicking the tick mark on the left. It will help others to troubleshoot similar issues.

Comment: not really, I am trying something else (: I will only use it for building my RestfulAPI