# Call local function in Node.js <%%> tag in a document

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using Node.js and trying to use a local function of a document that needs to use a JSON I send it in res.render. Is there a way to do it?
Example of the way I was trying to use it:

```
<%local_variable = localFunction(sent_JSON)%>
```

Edit: sorry if this is a simple question, I'm a newbie when it comes to web development.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
res.render('yourpage', {
    sent_JSON: yourJson,
});
```

Comment: It was sent, however I can't call local functions or variables in the document when i use the <%%> tag to use the sent JSON. I even printed it in the console when the page was loaded, showing that it's been sent correctly.

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30539675/13441500) might answer your question.

Comment: I've been trying that for the last hour, and it didn't work.